# ERROR:The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open. Why is this happening?

Tags: vb.net

Welcome to my problem first off thank you for taking a look , basically I am getting the error:

> The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.

even though I am clearly stating in my code that the connection is closing with `Connection.Close()` so I don't understand why it's doing this , maybe it's in the wrong place  for what i am trying to do but i really haven't a clue so maybe another pair of eyes might spot something wrong I have tried `if connection.state = open then connection.close()` and similar things but this error just comes up not matter I do. My code is below :

```
 Protected Sub OkBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles OkBtn.Click
    Dim ThisDay As Date = Date.Today
    Dim ThisUser As String
    ThisUser = Request.QueryString("")
    If ThisUser = "" Then
        ThisUser = "Chris Heywood"
    End If
    Dim transType As String
    transType = Request.QueryString("")
    If transType = "" Then
        transType = "Fire"
    End If
    connection.Open()
    command = New SqlCommand("Select * From FireTest Where [Trans Type]='Fire' AND Convert(date,[Date],103)=CONVERT(Date,GETDATE(),103)", connection)
    datareader = command.ExecuteReader()
    If datareader.HasRows = True Then
        datareader.Close()
        connection.Close()
        Exit Sub
    End If
    connection.Open()
    command = New SqlCommand("Insert Into FireTest([Date],[Type],[Comments],[Completed By],[Trans Type]) Values (@Date,@Type,@Comments,@CompletedBy, @TransType)", connection)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", ThisDay)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", DropDownList1.SelectedValue)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comments", TextBox1.Text)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompletedBy", ThisUser)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TransType", transType)
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    connection.Close()
    Response.Redirect("~/Production/Navigator.aspx")
End Sub
```

This is VB.NET code-behind from a ASP.NET front, thank you for reading at least answer will be marked it it reaches my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there some sort of connection.Dispose() command you can use? Fairly new to this myself and not using this specific language, but you never know, could work...

I would have commented, but apparently I need more reputation for that!

EDIT: It's possible in the code that you can open the connection, and then open it again without closing it as the Close method is in an if statement?

Comment: I know the feels man it's either answer or don't answer at all until a certain level , will give it a shot & see what happens.

Comment: Using this idea of yours help me realize that my connection.close was located in the wrong place , answer will be yours and thank you. it kind of solved my issue and as there are no other suggestions you will be flagged as marked.

Comment: Also the rep will help you out ;D

Comment: Thanks pal, I appreciate it, good job on getting it working ;D